# Games explorer group order is reversed

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I've formatted my PC to do a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64. I was adding the Spanish language pack and then removing the English one.

After removing the English LP, something weird happened to Games Explorer, the groups "Games" and "Game Provider" swapped position. Usually "Game Provider" is above "Games", when the position changed, "Games" went above "Game Provider". Check out the screenshot.

[image: Games and Game Provider swapped position]

I want to make "Games" be below "Game Provider" (like default).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer by myself just before submitting the question, but I want to answer this anyway for the people with the same issue.

The order of these groups are set in this submenu.

Right click the Games Explorer's blank space.

[image: Context Menu]

Go to Group by and then change from "Ascending" to "Descending" keeping "Type" as group method.